# AWS EC2, Load Balancer and Updating Craft

Tags: database, updates, manual-updates, aws, load-balancer

I have a pretty large Craft site that needs to be load balanced with multiple ec2 instances and one RDS mysql instance. Everything is working great, except for I noticed that if I get to the admin panel and run updates on craft/plugins. The site files only change on the ec2 instance i'm on.

Is there a way to update all my ec2 instances at once on update?

Thanks! Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't update Craft or any plugins on production.

Do the updates on a local/dev version of the site, commit the resulting changes, then deploy those to all of your EC2 instances with a CI/CD service like https://buddy.works or whatever your favorite service is.

Some related blog posts worth reading:

https://nystudio107.com/blog/database-asset-syncing-between-environments-in-craft-cms

https://nystudio107.com/blog/local-development-with-vagrant-homestead

Comment: Thank you for the response! 

So just to clarify, if I update craft locally with a clone of the production database, do I also have to re-import the database I have on my local machine to production? Or is craft smart enough to see the file changes and update the database as needed?

Comment: It won't automatically happen. It depends on the changes that you might have made locally and if things on production have changed as well. Craft's project config or content migrations are potential solutions.